# Show location on Yahoo maps using lat/long

Tags: javascript, api, yahoo, yahoo-maps

I have latitude and longitude , for example -25.363882, 131.044922(taken from google maps example). How can I show the location on **Yahoo maps** using the longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ajax/#ex6

Answer (score 1):

As per I understood that you are trying for Reverse Geocoding with Yahoo Maps.For reference please check out:

http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/maps/examples/YahooMap_Geocoding/srcview/index.html

The above example is in Flex.As you can check the code using javascript.